# Azure File Storage using PHP

Tags: php, sdk, azure-webapps, azure-files

I want to run a single webpage to display files, which are stored in an Azure File Storage. It must be Azure File storage because these files came from a Docker container, which is mounted, to that file storage.

I have a Azure Container Instance witch stores PDF files in an Azure File Storage. Now I run a WebApp (PHP) that shall read all the PDFs.

I’ve installed the Microsoft Azure Storage File PHP SDK but have no clue how to use it. Even the [sample.php](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/tests/Functional/File/FileServiceFunctionalTest.php) did not help me coming forward. It would be very helpful if someone could help me a bit a simple sniped.

[image: Service]

Comment: You can have look into https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-azure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you want to directly display a PDF file from Azure File Storage in a web page. Generally, the best practice is to generate the url with sas token of a file in Azure File Storage.

So I followed the GitHub repo [`Azure/azure-storage-php`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php) to install Azure File Storage SDK for PHP in my sample project, here is my sample code and its dependencies.

The file structure of my sample project is as the figure below.

[image]

The content of my `composer.json` file is as below.

```
{
  "require": {
    "microsoft/azure-storage-file": "*"
  }
}
```

My sample PHP file `demo.php` is as below, that's inspired by the function `generateFileDownloadLinkWithSAS` of the offical sample [`azure-storage-php/samples/FileSamples.php`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/samples/FileSamples.php#L235).

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; 
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Internal\Resources;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\File\FileSharedAccessSignatureHelper;

$accountName = "<your account name>";
$accountKey = "<your account key>";

$shareName = "<your share name>";
$fileName = "<your pdf file name>";

$now = date(DATE_ISO8601);
$date = date_create($now);
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 hour"));
$expiry = str_replace("+0000", "Z", date_format($date, DATE_ISO8601));

$helper = new FileSharedAccessSignatureHelper($accountName, $accountKey);
$sas = $helper->generateFileServiceSharedAccessSignatureToken(
        Resources::RESOURCE_TYPE_FILE,
        "$shareName/$fileName",
        'r',                        // Read
        $expiry // A valid ISO 8601 format expiry time， such as '2020-01-01T08:30:00Z' 
    );
$fileUrlWithSAS = "https://$accountName.file.core.windows.net/$shareName/$fileName?$sas";
echo "<h1>Demo to display PDF from Azure File Storage</h1>";
echo "<iframe src='$fileUrlWithSAS'  width='800' height='500' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>";
?>
```

The result of my web page is as the figures below in Chrome and Firefox.

The result in Chrome:

[image]

The result in Firefox:

[image]

---

Update: The code to list files in a file share, as below.

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; 
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\File\FileRestProxy;

$accountName = "<your account name>";
$accountKey = "<your account key>";

$shareName = "<your share name>";

$connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=$accountName;AccountKey=$accountKey";
$fileClient = FileRestProxy::createFileService($connectionString);

$list = $fileClient->listDirectoriesAndFiles($shareName);

function endsWith( $str, $sub ) {
    return ( substr( $str, strlen( $str ) - strlen( $sub ) ) === $sub );
}

foreach($list->getFiles() as &$file) {
    $fileName = $file->getName();
    if(endsWith($fileName, ".pdf")) {
        echo $fileName."\n";
    }
};
?>
```

Comment: that is very close to what I'm looking for or better say the second step in order to open/download the pdf. In a first step, I'll need to look in the file share to list all stored pdf files. Let's say, if I get back an array, I can build a table and then your code (I tested it already successful) would be the second step.

Comment: @RafaelCamisonR I have update my answer for the code of the first step to list files with `.pdf` suffix name.